Google Cloud Composer creation failing for all types of environment sizes and versions: GKE pods failed to become healthy
I am trying to create a Google Cloud Composer instance. Composer V1 has ended support. So, only option is to create with V2 which is where its failing due to below error.
Configurations used:
GCP Account Type: Free trial
Composer version: composer-2.8.1-airflow-2.7.3
Environment sizes tried: Small, medium, large, custom
Location: us-central1
Custome Env Size config:
Scheduler: 1 scheduler with 1 vCPU, 2 GB memory, 1 GB storage
Triggerer: 1 triggerer with 1 vCPU, 1 GB memory, 1 GB storage
Web server: 1 vCPU, 2 GB memory, 1 GB storage
Worker: Autoscaling between 1 and 3 workers, with 1 vCPU, 2 GB memory, 1 GB storage each
Error:
CREATE operation on this environment failed 2 days ago with the following error message:
Some of the GKE pods failed to become healthy. Please check the GKE logs for details, and retry the operation.
I did further checked the GKE logs and under workloads, found the pods are unschedulable but i am not able to understand the exact cause. Even the logs does not show any detailed error.
I tried with multiple times for retry but every time its failing with same error.
I want to launch the composer instance

After migrating to use version 3 of Composer, the issue was resolved.  It's important to note that this version is not mentioned in the console, so you need to use the command line to specify it. Here is the gcloud config that worked for me:
--image-version composer-3-airflow-2.7.3-build.5
--location us-central1
I hope this helps you if you face a similar issue.

I'm having the same issue, and I recommend you file a support case with GCP so these instances can be counted and investigated. I've made many environments , and this particular case is a Dev project and has had no setting changes to speak of, as well as 4 existing environments.
What I'm saying is, the issue is hard to parse because it involved 53 minutes per instance of logging to examine, so we especially need to engage support cases in hopes that someone who has access we dont (Google) can identify an issue on the side of those who are controlling the "composer agent".
In my case, there is actually a successful GKE cluster creation, but there is a loop that the gcsFuse mounting process runs into that loops for 30 minutes.
Please add detail if you'd like here, but I still encourage the support case. Someone else on Google Cloud Community boards has also reported this issue.
Thank you

Resolved this issue with composer 3 version available directly on the cloud composer UI now.

Is it a private env or a public env.? if it's a private env I'd check if the IP are getting exhausted which can result in the same behavior.
Also when it says pod's are unschedulable, you can check the details/events (or gke cluster logs) to figure out what is causing this behavior.

With the release from 2024-05-11 the mentioned that a minimum of 600GB  Persistent disk SSD (GB) is required. Which is above the 500GB default quota. That's why your Composer creation failed.
The process (request + approval) to increase your quota in a region took a couple of minutes.
Good to hear that this issue is resolved with Composer v3

Resolved this issue with composer 3 version available directly on the cloud composer UI now.

This could use a little more information if possible.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
